# 'Access is denied' to Python 3.8 for PyCharm on Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pycharm

Attempting to create a new project in PyCharm Community on Windows 10. Here are the settings for new project in PyCharm:

[image: Settings for new project in PyCharm]

I'm greeted with the error msg:

```
Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe" 
(in directory "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0"): CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
```

The only workarounds I've found on SO so far are:

1. Change WindowsApp folder owner to 'everyone'
2. Create new 'venv' and put project in there
3. Don't use Python from Windows Store

Would it be best to ditch Windows Store Python and just download Python 3.8 for Windows from python.org?  I'm new to Python development and don't want to adopt sloppy behavior.

Comment: No idea what's the issue here or if it happens because of Windows Store, but yeah I would absolutely only install Python from python.org when using Windows. Just uninstall your current one and reinstall from the python website, if everything works then that's that.

Comment: Thanks!  Removing the Windows Store version and whitelisting (in Windows Security) PyCharm install and project dir cleared up all errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the Windows Store version and whitelisting in Windows Security PyCharm exe and project directories cleared up all launch issues in PyCharm!

Comment: Could you please elaborate ?

Comment: Yea, how the heck do you whitelist?

Answer (score 3):

Use `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe` as Base Interpreter

Answer (score 0):

Received the same error when trying to install the Python 'pynorm' package on Windows 10 after installing Python from the Microsoft store. The following worked for me

1. Logged in as Administrator in Window 10 Pro
2. Uninstalled the Microsoft Store and all previous Python versions from add/remove programs
3. Rebooted the PC
4. Downloaded / Installed Python 3.9.6 from python.org
5. Installed pynorm